# OS X 10.8 hosts file completely ignoring new entries. Help!

Tags: macos, file, hosts

I have a hosts file that I've added a couple URLs to a while back and it's been working fine, but any new entries now get completely ignored. I've added these to test it...

`google.com      test-domain.com`

`google.com      www.test-domain.com`

And I've read through a bunch of posts about this issue. It makes no difference if I put them at the top or the bottom of the file, nor if I follow the entries with 2 carriage returns.

I'm totally at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't enter those values. That's not how the hosts file works. You need to direct an ip to a domain. You can't redirect based on domains. So you'll need to enter 127.0.0.1 test-domain.com to have 127.0.0.1 as the routable address when test-domain.com is entered into a browser (or other).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the `/etc/hosts` file on UNIX systems is intended to map IP addresses to hostnames and vice-versa. You have not added IP address information for these hosts.

See the man page for more information by typing the following at the command line:

```
man 5 hosts
```

You haven't specified how you are attempting to use this file or the records inside of it, so it's hard to say why it was working previously.